# Send Encrypted messages over MQTT

Tags: mqtt, paho

I am just researching about sending encrypted messages over MQTT. I encrypted a message with public key published over MQTT and the receiver will decrypt the message with private key.

I tried with a RSA 512 bit key to encrypt data but on receiving end I received message in numbers.

I have read about only certificate files that can provide security but this will ensure security for clients with same broker. Is there any other method so I can send encrypted data to other MQTT broker?

Is there any method to encrypt and decrypt message, I am using Paho MQTT v3 and Java?

Thanks

Comment: There are 2 totally separate things here, running MQTT over a SSL/TLS connection which will encrypt all traffic, but messages will be in the clear and encrypting the message payload. It is not totally clear which you mean. I think it is the latter, in which case show the code you have tried and somebody will probably help you fix it. MQTT payloads are just byte arrays, you should be able to send encrypted message payload just fine

Comment: i got it, i was doing some stupid mistakes thanks @hardillb you r really master